# Saving Canvas Drawing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've created an app that lets the user draw a picture onto a Canvas. I would like the user to also be able to save that drawing to his Media Library. I've looked up info on IsolatedStorage but that's not exactly what I want, or am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render you canvas to a `WriteableBitmap`

```
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);
bitmap.Render(canvas, null);
bitmap.Invalidate();
```

You can then encode this as a JPEG and save to isolated storage as described in [this blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images).

Answer (score 1):

Use the MediaLibrary SavePictureToCameraRoll method. See this article for a full exmaple:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)